# Training accuracy showing 0.0

Tags: tensorflow

My code:

```
def accuracy(pred_labels,true_labels):
    true_labels = tf.cast(tf.reshape(true_labels,[-1,1]),tf.float32)
    correct_pred = tf.equal(pred_labels,true_labels)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))
    return accuracy
```

When I run:

```
feed_images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,96,96,3))
feed_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,))
logits = nn_model(feed_images)
cost = loss(logits,feed_labels)
opt_adam = optimizer(cost)
acc = accuracy(logits,feed_labels)
feed_trdict={feed_images:ni,feed_labels:nl}
tr_acc = sess.run(acc,feed_dict = feed_trdict)
```

I get training accuracy is 0.0 for all successive iterations.
However that shouldn't be so.
I can't understand, what is wrong with the code. I saw the code for calculating accuracy on a blog site(Only the `accuracy` function code)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is (probably) that `pred_labels` are **not** the `logits`. Trying something along the lines

```
correct = tf.cast(tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, true_labels, 1), tf.float32, name='correct')
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct, name='accuracy')
```

might help.

I do not understand, why questions do not contain a MWE **with** some example data to reproduce this effect. Otherwise, all we can do is using a crystal ball to guess what is causing this effect.

Comment: But in this line `acc = accuracy(logits,feed_labels)` I am passing the `logits` as argument

Comment: And **this** is the mistake! You need to pass the predicted labels in `pred_labels` and not the logits. The variable-name is not a random choice.

Comment: `pred_labels = tf.argmax(logits,1)` will do the job, right?

Comment: Comments are not a chat in stackoverflow. But your approach is an alternative way. So yes.

Comment: Using your method I am only getting accuracy of the values 30%, 10% and 0.0%. i am getting these values repeatedly

Comment: And also by using this `pred_labels = tf.argmax(logits,1)`. The consecutive accuracy values I am getting are 30.0 20.0 20.0 10.0 20.0 10.0 0.0...

Comment: Can you suggest any solution? @Patwie